# Look for a configuration file with Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I written a Ruby tool, named `foobar`, having a default configuration into a
file (called `.foobar`).

When the tool is executed without any params, the configuration file's params
can be used: `~/.foobar`.

But, if the current tool's path is `~/projects/foobar` and if
`~/projects/foobar/.foobar` exists, then this file should be used instead of
`~/.foobar`.

That's why the way to look for this configuration file should start from the
current folder until the current user folder.

Is there a simple way to look for this file?

Comment: please, please move ~/.foobar in ~/.config/foobar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cfg_file = File.open(".foobar", "r") rescue File.open("~/.foobar", "r")
```

Although to be honest, I almost always do two things: provide an option for a config file path, and allow overriding of default config values. The problem with the latter is that unless you know config files are ordered/have precedence, it can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
if File.exists(".foobar")
    # open .foobar
else
    # open ~/..
end
```